# masterdetail flow with images

Tags: android, image, master-detail

I'm very new to developing android apps and my programing experience is also lacking a bit. 
But I hope some of you can still help me.

Let's get to my problem.

I created a list with images. If I click on one item, I get a Toast saying `"you clicked xy"`. But I want to include a master detail flow. I looked up the internet for some help but all I could find were tutorials on how to integrate a website...

This is my `onCreate` method, I hope someone could help me.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you figure this out and have an answer to post? It's ok to post your own answer if the others don't help you enough that you want to accept them

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches - using fragments or using activities. Fragments are the preferred way, but harder. Seeing as you are new to android you should probably learn how to do it with activities first. Before you can do that you need to learn about [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

What you need to do is use the intent to start the detail activity when your item is selected.

**Master activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... 
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        //you should make the key string a constant in your code
        //im assuming for this example your item is something like a drawable resource id
        intent.putExtra("ImageId", getItem(position));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

**Detail activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ... 
   ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(...);
   int imageRes = getIntent().getIntExtra("ImageId", -1);
   if (imgRes > 0){
       iv.setImageResource(imageRes);
   } 
}
```